# Fontawesome license throwing error while installing using npm

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, font-awesome, font-awesome-5

As per [fontawesome's documentation](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/setup/using-package-managers) I am trying to install pro version of fontawesome 5.
I have created a .npmrc file where licence and registry have been mentioned.

Now I am trying to run **npm install --save-dev @fortawesome/fontawesome-pro**.
It is throwing error Bearer token value is not a legal HTTP header value. I have attached a snapshot for the same. [image: Error Snapshot]

Adding folder structure:

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The message can be a bit misleading. This error can occur if your token is very old *(I've had this happen a few times myself)*

**Try to regenerate your `_auth_token` from the fontawesome page**:

[image]

If you don't mind a global token *(if you do not work with several licenses)*, you can enable the Pro license globally like so:

```
#: npm config set "@fortawesome:registry" https://npm.fontawesome.com/

#: npm config set "//npm.fontawesome.com/:_authToken" TOKEN_GOES_HERE
```

If you work with for instance docker containers, a better solution is to set environment variables like so:

```
#: FONTAWESOME_NPM_AUTH_TOKEN=YOUR_TOKEN_GOES_HERE npm install --save @fortawesome/fontawesome-pro
```

or set the `.npmrc` file with:

```
@fortawesome:registry=https://npm.fontawesome.com/
//npm.fontawesome.com/:_authToken=${FONTAWESOME_NPM_AUTH_TOKEN}
```

But try to regenerate the token and re-run your commands.

Comment: Should this really be `@fortawesome` and not "fontawesome" ?

Comment: Yes, it should be `@fortawesome`. It is not a typo.